# How to make Quokka.js Untitled file to be ignored by Eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, quokka.js

I have a JS project with strict ESLint rules and `"eslint.run": "onType"` setting. I would like to ignore new Quokka.js Untitled editors, which are just a playground and I do not want to bother with clean syntax there. Is there any way how to disable VS Code ESLint for Quokka Untitled editors?

A possible workaround could be to automatically add a line `/* eslint-disable */` to every Quokka.js New JavaScript File, but I also do not know if it's possible. (Maybe by a Quokka.js plugin, but that's the last option due to complexity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESLint extension in VSCode has a `Eslint: Ignore Untitled` option which solved the issue for me.

Comment: It does ignore new source files created by File > New Text File (and changing language to *Javascript*). But I do not use it - I create new files with a name in a folder. So, I consider this answer as the best so far.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've created a code snippet:

```json
    "Quokka": {
        "prefix": "Quokka",
        "body": ["/* eslint-disable */", "//... may have other lines ..."]
    }
```

And insert it when I open new Quokka window.

Answer (score -1):

in your `eslintrc.json` add

```json
"files": [ 
  {
    "patterns": "**/*()" // For Quokka files -> dont have a valid file extension
  }
],
```

Comment: This disables eslint in all files, including `*.js` files. (I have Windows OS).

Comment: true, I didnt check that. I have been playing around some more, but couldnt figure it out. I created an issue on github, you can track it if you want https://github.com/wallabyjs/quokka/issues/764